# InfluxDb - Flux - If condition on count

Tags: time-series, influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I am trying to put an if condition in flux based on count. Following is the use case

```
//pseudo code
If (count > 0) the
  //Show results from bucket A
else
 //Show results from bucket B
```

I am unable to figure out what is right way of checking this, following is the actual flux

```
if from(bucket: "mytestbucket")
      |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "main_power_availability")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
      |> count() > 0
   then
    from(bucket: "mytestbucket")
      |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "main_power_availability")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
      |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: max, createEmpty: true)
      |> fill(usePrevious: true)
      |> yield(name: "max")
    else
      _lastvalue
      |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "main_power_availability")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
      |> aggregateWindow(every: 5m, fn: max)
      |> fill(usePrevious: true)
      |> yield(name: "max")
```

But I get an error `stream[A] is not Comparable`.

I have verified that count return correct result see below

[image: Grafana screenshot]

The thing missing here is how to compare count integer value in condition, apparently it is comparing the returned table stream with integer value `0` and throwing this error. Have tried [https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0/stdlib/universe/findcolumn/`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0/stdlib/universe/findcolumn/%60) without luck. I assume it would be a simple stuff yet hard to figure out from me from flux documentation.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a variable.

```
count = from(bucket: "mytestbucket")
      |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["entity_id"] == "main_power_availability")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
      |> count()

if count > 0 ...
```